# Open Play 2 project from IDEA Ultimate in IDEA Community Edition

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I've got a Scala Play 2.4 project that was created in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition. When I open it in IDEA Community Edition and try to run it, I need to setup a run configuration.

[image: Edit configuration dialog]

It looks like there's a run configuration that the community edition can't understand (Play2Run in the screenshot). How can I get this to run in the community edition?

Comment: I don't think Play2 projects aren't supported in the community version of IntelliJ IDEA. But since a Play project is nothing more than an SBT project, you could define the run configuration using an SBT task (not tested though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Play framework is a feature available only in Intellij IDEA Ultimate version.

See:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/

Comment: Hm. There is a Scala plugin for Community though, and it is described with the text: "Scala, SBT, SSP, HOCON and Play 2 support".

Comment: You may be able to get the build running, you will certainly get highlighting in Scala source files, but you won't get routes -> controller navigation, not sure about play view templates etc..

Answer (score 1):

1.install Scala plugin
2.open the terminal in idea
3.you can run sbt compile now
4.if you want to debug your application, use sbt run -jvm-debug :port and then add a configuration to attach to the specific port